# How do I move the installation folders of Steam games that have shared content to another drive?

Tags: steam

I was trying to [move the installation folder of my Steam games](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/4BD4-4528-6B2E-8327#move), *Counter-Strike: Condition Zero* and *Counter-Strike: Condition Zero Deleted Scenes*, but have encountered the following error message:

> Moving content for the following apps has failed:
> - Counter-Strike: Condition Zero Deleted Scenes: has shared content
> - Counter-Strike: Condition Zero: has shared content

[image]

I initially tried moving the two individually but got presented with the same error message.

**How do I move the installation folders of Steam games that have shared content to another drive?** How do I identify which other games are sharing content with these games so I can move them too?

Comment: Have you tried manually moving both game folders, uninstalling them in Steam (still thinking they're in their original location, and re-installing them in the library they currently reside in? Steam will usually find the existing files and simply verify the files.

Comment: @Joachim I have not yet tried doing that. I'll edit the question when I do.

Answer (score 5):

Both Condition Zero and Condition Zero Deleted Scenes depend on the Half Life folder, as they are considered Half Life mods under the hood.

You can see it in this picture that I only have CS:CZDS installed and magically I have a Half Life folder.

[image]

But when I try to move it, I get the same error as you because CS:CZDS is installed into the Half Life folder, instead of it's own folder.

[image]

There are two possible solutions:

- You uninstall CS:CZ and CS:CZDS and install it in the target Steam folder
- You move the entire Half Life folder to the target Steam directory, uninstall the games that use the HL folder and make Steam "install" them again, this will not reinstall the games but verify the integrity of the existing files